# DotNetNuke (DNN) 8 Built In Web Services API

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-8

Does DotNetNuke have a built in web services API I can call or do I have to create my own end point?  All the documentation I can find about the services framework talks about creating your own module with a service to extend theirs.  What I would like to do is authenticate against an existing / built in web service that will allow me to create users from an external application.  A similar example would be me calling the built in SharePoint web services to retrieve list information with an external application.  I don't have to write anything in SharePoint to call the built in web services.  They are just there.

If this built in service(s) does exist do you have a link or some sample code about how to call it without writing my own web service module?

Thanks,

Bill

Answer (score 1):

DNN does not (as of version 9.1) have a (supported) external API.  There are web services designed to the internal modules to use, but you have to get a little hacky in order to make them usable outside of the site.  There has been talk of creating a more standard API like this, but until the happens the scenario requires that you create specific APIs for your exact purposes.